# Plugin custom post type - Internal server Error

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types

I need to create a plugin in wordpress 3.9 for custom post types.When i activate the plugin, am getting an internal server error 500. Also plugins are not listing in admin dashboard. Here is my code:

```
<?php  
/**
* Plugin Name: Name Of The Plugin
* Plugin URI: http://URI_Of_Page_Describing_Plugin_and_Updates
* Description: A brief description of the Plugin.
* Version: The Plugin's Version Number, e.g.: 1.0
* Author: Name Of The Plugin Author
* Author URI: http://URI_Of_The_Plugin_Author
* License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL2
*/

add_action('init', 'register_wp_questions');

$labels = array(
'name' => __( 'Questions', 'wp_question' ),
'singular_name' => __( 'Question', 'wp_question' ),
'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'wp_question' ),
'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Question', 'wp_question' ),
'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Questions', 'wp_question' ),
'new_item' => __( 'New Question', 'wp_question' ),
'view_item' => __( 'View Question', 'wp_question' ),
'search_items' => __( 'Search Questions', 'wp_question' ),
'not_found' => __( 'No Questions found', 'wp_question' ),
'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Questions found in Trash','wp_question' ),
'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Question:', 'wp_question'),
'menu_name' => __( 'Questions', 'wp_question' )
);


$args = array(
'labels' => $labels,
'hierarchical' => true,
'description'  => __( 'Questions and Answers', 'wp_question' ),
'supports'     => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments' ),
'public'       => true,
'show_ui'       => true,
'show_in_menu'       => true,
'show_in_nav_menus'       => true,
'publicly_queryable'       => true,
'exclude_from_search'       => true,
'has_archive'       => true,
'query_var'       => true,
'can_export'       => true,
'rewrite'       => true,
'capability_type'       => true
);

register_post_type ('wp_question', $args);

?>
```

Please help. How can i figure out the error?

Thanks

Comment: Check the first array, the last item in it has comma, it shouldnt be there na?

Comment: yeah i have removed that, but still not working.Is the code format is correct?

Comment: Actually when i activate the plugin it will not load even the admin dashboard.

Comment: Can you say the exact error?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `add_action('init', 'register_wp_questions');` do in your plugin. At this stage this is your problem. You are hooking a function to `init` that does not exist, thus giving you an error.

I suppose that you need to register and hook your CPT to the `init` hook. You should actually put all that code in a function and then add it to the `init` hook. Your code should be

```
<?php  
/**
* Plugin Name: Name Of The Plugin
* Plugin URI: http://URI_Of_Page_Describing_Plugin_and_Updates
* Description: A brief description of the Plugin.
* Version: The Plugin's Version Number, e.g.: 1.0
* Author: Name Of The Plugin Author
* Author URI: http://URI_Of_The_Plugin_Author
* License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL2
*/

add_action('init', 'register_wp_questions');

function register_wp_questions() {
$labels = array(
'name' => __( 'Questions', 'wp_question' ),
'singular_name' => __( 'Question', 'wp_question' ),
'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'wp_question' ),
'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Question', 'wp_question' ),
'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Questions', 'wp_question' ),
'new_item' => __( 'New Question', 'wp_question' ),
'view_item' => __( 'View Question', 'wp_question' ),
'search_items' => __( 'Search Questions', 'wp_question' ),
'not_found' => __( 'No Questions found', 'wp_question' ),
'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Questions found in Trash','wp_question' ),
'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Question:', 'wp_question'),
'menu_name' => __( 'Questions', 'wp_question' )
);


$args = array(
'labels' => $labels,
'hierarchical' => true,
'description'  => __( 'Questions and Answers', 'wp_question' ),
'supports'     => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments' ),
'public'       => true,
'show_ui'       => true,
'show_in_menu'       => true,
'show_in_nav_menus'       => true,
'publicly_queryable'       => true,
'exclude_from_search'       => true,
'has_archive'       => true,
'query_var'       => true,
'can_export'       => true,
'rewrite'       => true,
'capability_type'       => true
);

register_post_type ('wp_question', $args);

}

?>
```

Comment: oh yeah!  i forgot to place the function in my code. It is my mistake..anyways thanks for the help :)

Comment: My pleasure. Glad I could help

Comment: One more issue is there, i cant find the option for adding custom post type in Admin Dashboard.But i could activate the plugin.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to your code, as everything checks out from what I can see. Your CPT should be below comments. This might be a problem with capabilities set. Check out the codex on [`register_post_type`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

Comment: i got it, i have to give the 'capability_type' field to 'post' instead of true.Thanks @Pieter Goosen :)